# TextEditingController cannot set value from Dialog

Tags: flutter

I am having an issue. Basically what i am trying to do is when user tap on the textfield, it will pop up a list dialog. When i click value from the list, it will populate textfield value in the main page. But somehow, I cannot set the TextEditingController value when i click value from my ListView Dialog. I am not sure why this is happening. Am i missing something? Or is there any better way to do this? Please help me.

[image: ListView Dialog to choose activity]

ActivityListDialog Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    import '../resources/constants.dart' as constant;
    
    // ignore: must_be_immutable
    class MyActivityList extends StatefulWidget {
      MyActivityList(
          {required this.controller});
    
      TextEditingController controller;
    
      @override
      _MyActivityListState createState() => _MyActivityListState();
    }
    
    class _MyActivityListState extends State<MyActivityList> {
      TextEditingController _textControllerSearch = TextEditingController();
    
      Iterable newDataList = List.from(constant.activityList);
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _textControllerSearch.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      onItemChanged(String value) {
        setState(() {
          newDataList = constant.activityList
              .where((string) => string.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
              .toList();
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Dialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          child: contentBox(context),
        );
      }
    
      contentBox(context) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: 500.0,
                maxHeight: 500.0,
              ),
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _textControllerSearch,
                      cursorColor: constant.colorGrey,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search',
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: constant.colorGrey),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: constant.colorGrey),
                        ),
                        border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: constant.colorGrey),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: onItemChanged,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      children: newDataList.map((data) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(data),
                          onTap: (){
                            setState(() {
                              print(data);
                              widget.controller.text = data.toString();
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Main Page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../customs/my_activitylist.dart';
import '../resources/constants.dart' as constant;

class CreateEventPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateEventPageState createState() => _CreateEventPageState();
}

class _CreateEventPageState extends State<CreateEventPage> {

  TextEditingController _controllerActivity = TextEditingController();



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Create Event"),
        titleSpacing: 40.0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            Stepper(
              type: StepperType.vertical,
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              currentStep: _currentStep,
              onStepTapped: (step) => _tapped(step),
              onStepContinue: _continued,
              onStepCancel: _cancel,
              steps: <Step>[
                Step(
                  title: Text("Details"),
                  content: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      MyTextField(
                          label: "Activity",
                          isReadOnly: true,
                          onTap: () {
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  return MyActivityList(
                                    controller: _controllerActivity,
                                  );
                                });
                            FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();
                          })
                    ],
                  ),
                  isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
                  state: _currentStep >= 0
                      ? StepState.complete
                      : StepState.disabled,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _tapped(int step) {
    setState(() => _currentStep = step);
  }

  _continued() {
    setState(() {
      _validateStartDate();
      _validateEndDate();
      if (_isValidStartDateTime && _isValidEndDateTime) {
        if (_currentStep < 2) {
          _currentStep += 1;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  _cancel() {
    _currentStep > 0 ? setState(() => _currentStep -= 1) : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) for updating widgets inside dialogs. The dialog widget should be wrapped by it. Use the setState function of that StatefulBuilder. You can check this [link](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/can-stateful-builder-step-into-shoes-of-stateful-widget-81af58824ed0) for more info.